Depending on a flag in the request body, how do i return bulk JSON or SSE on the same route in a quarkus app?
Let's say I have a quarkus resource like the following:
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/some")
public class SomeResource {
    @Inject
    SomeService service;

    @POST
    @Path("/path")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RestStreamElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Multi<SomeResponse> streamResponses(@Body SomeRequest someRequest) {
        return service.stream(someRequest);
    }
}

and the SomeRequest class can contain a flag called stream, which indicates if the response should be streamed or returned as bulk json request. The service already has the capability to return bulk json. How can i return bulk responses or stream responses on the same route depending on the stream flag?
The resource with the additional endpoint should look something like this:
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/some")
public class SomeResource {
    @Inject
    SomeService service;

    @POST
    @Path("/path")
    @Produces(MediaType.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RestStreamElementType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Multi<SomeResponse> streamResponses(@Body SomeRequest someRequest) {
        return service.stream(someRequest);
    }
    
    @POST
    @Path("/path")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public SomeResponse streamResponses(@Body SomeRequest someRequest) {
        return service.chat(someRequest);
    }

}

I have tried to use Reactive Routes, but could not find out how to conditionally set the return type correctely. Using a Uni resulted in the wrong content-type of the response

When you say bulk return, what do you mean exactly?

@geoand let's say SomeResponse is a message, represented by a String field called message. In the Multi endpoint this message will be streamed in parts, in the other enpoint the whole message will be returned. For the message "This is a message", there would be 4 responses from the multi method with one word each and only one response from the other endpoint
